# Implementing back propagation using numpy and python for cleveland dataset

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, backpropagation, gradient-descent

I wanted to predict heart disease using backpropagation algorithm for neural networks. For this I used UCI heart disease data set linked here: [processed cleveland](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/heart-disease/processed.cleveland.data). To do this, I used the cde found on the following blog: [Build a flexible Neural Network with Backpropagation in Python](https://dev.to/shamdasani/build-a-flexible-neural-network-with-backpropagation-in-python) and changed it little bit according to my own dataset. My code is as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open("cleveland_data.csv"), delimiter=",")
x = list(reader)
result = np.array(x).astype("float")

X = result[:, :13]
y0 = result[:, 13]
y1 = np.array([y0])
y = y1.T

# scale units
X = X / np.amax(X, axis=0)  # maximum of X array

class Neural_Network(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # parameters
        self.inputSize = 13
        self.outputSize = 1
        self.hiddenSize = 13

        # weights
        self.W1 = np.random.randn(self.inputSize, self.hiddenSize)  
        self.W2 = np.random.randn(self.hiddenSize, self.outputSize)  

    def forward(self, X):
        # forward propagation through our network
        self.z = np.dot(X, self.W1)  
        self.z2 = self.sigmoid(self.z)  # activation function
        self.z3 = np.dot(self.z2, self.W2)  
        o = self.sigmoid(self.z3)  # final activation function
        return o

    def sigmoid(self, s):
        # activation function
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-s))

    def sigmoidPrime(self, s):
        # derivative of sigmoid
        return s * (1 - s)

    def backward(self, X, y, o):
        # backward propgate through the network
        self.o_error = y - o  # error in output
        self.o_delta = self.o_error * self.sigmoidPrime(o)  # applying derivative of sigmoid to error

        self.z2_error = self.o_delta.dot(
            self.W2.T)  # z2 error: how much our hidden layer weights contributed to output error
        self.z2_delta = self.z2_error * self.sigmoidPrime(self.z2)  # applying derivative of sigmoid to z2 error

        self.W1 += X.T.dot(self.z2_delta)  # adjusting first set (input --> hidden) weights
        self.W2 += self.z2.T.dot(self.o_delta)  # adjusting second set (hidden --> output) weights

    def train(self, X, y):
        o = self.forward(X)
        self.backward(X, y, o)


NN = Neural_Network()
for i in range(100):  # trains the NN 100 times
    print("Input: \n" + str(X))
    print("Actual Output: \n" + str(y))
    print("Predicted Output: \n" + str(NN.forward(X)))
    print("Loss: \n" + str(np.mean(np.square(y - NN.forward(X)))))  # mean sum squared loss
    print("\n")
    NN.train(X, y)
```

But when I run this code, my all predicted outputs become = 1 after few iterations and then stays the same for up to all 100 iterations. what is the problem in the code?

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
Please explain more about where your program is deviating from the expected results.

Comment: I think something is wrong with my logic of back propagation which makes the predicted outputs = 1 after few iterations.

Answer (score 3):

Few mistakes that I've noticed:

- The output of your network is a sigmoid, i.e. a value between `[0, 1]` -- suits for predicting probabilities. But the target seems to be a value between `[0, 4]`. This explains the desire of the network to maximize the output to get as close as possible to large labels. But it can't go more than `1.0` and gets stuck.

  You should either get rid of the final sigmoid or pre-process the label and scale it to `[0, 1]`. Both options will make it learn better.
- You don't use the learning rate (effectively setting it to `1.0`), which is probably a bit high, so it's possible for the NN to diverge. My experiments showed that `0.01` is a good learning rate, but you can play around with that.

Other than this, your backprop seems working right.